# Sending email with akka actor in Play Framework 2.4

Tags: playframework, akka

How to send an email after 24 hours and 72 hours if I have an action for updating an record in database using Play Framework 2.4 and Akka Actor.

Answer (score 0):

- Save task in db
- Periodically query the db if there's something to be sent out: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAkka#Scheduling-asynchronous-tasks